# Scrolling back through the RStudio console

Tags: r, console, rstudio

This is just a RStudio interface question:

When scrolling back through the console to see my work and outputs I can only scroll back so far. Is there a way to open up the console and scroll back through *everything* I have done?

Sometimes I want to check results of a very long list, or I forget to write code in the script box instead of the console and want to scroll back to review it.

Cheers,

Comment: Once upon a time it [wasn't possible to customise the line limit](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200664587-Console-line-limit) - not sure if this is still the case. You could use `sink`, but then you won't see the output in the console (it'll be diverted to e.g. a text file).

Comment: If you're in the same R session, you can call the list up again from the history pane.  And if it was the very last call, then there's also `.Last.value`

Comment: Why not use the history tab (next to the environment tab)?

Comment: @jaysunice3401 My understanding is that the OP wants access to old *outputs*, not old inputs.

Comment: both! @RichardScriven solved half my problem. Thank you all for weighing in.

Comment: While we're at it, then, you can (1) use the up/down arrows to flip through past commands, or (2) type something that begins an expression previously executed (e.g. `plot`), then press `CTRL`+`up arrow` to pop up a menu of matching expressions.

Comment: Well this is from 11 months ago but they haven't seem to have changed it yet https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200656473-console?locale=en-us

Comment: Thanks for the answers, in my case I am displaying on the R console, a dozen of objects. It is too cumbersome to store them all in a list and save the list. The simplest for me would be: either to have no console limit or be able to store whatever is displayed on the console. The answers are limited to the case where the user wants to display one unique dataframe. How should I go about my issue? Thks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the excellent comments of others, if you have a data.frame called df with 2000 rows and 2 columns, to view all of them, type on the console:

```
utils::View(df) # opens a new separate window to view all the records.
```

In order to view just 500:1000 records of the data.frame just do:

```
utils::View(df[500:1000,])
```

Answer (score 3):

To build on jbaums's comment, I personally got really tired of typing `.Last.value` whenever I wanted to grab a temporary variable (especially when in Matlab its just `ans` and in Python its `_`.)

So as a workaround you can bind `ans` to `Last.value` to save yourself some time typing: `makeActiveBinding("ans", function(){.Last.value}, .GlobalEnv)`.

As a super-lame example of how this could be super-helpful at times:

```
> runif(5)  # Oh no! I forgot to assign my function output to a variable!
[1] 0.1905214 0.2175722 0.1140303 0.2645469 0.8298856
> ans  # Oh wait, we're good :)
[1] 0.1905214 0.2175722 0.1140303 0.2645469 0.8298856
```

To make it a bit more permanent, save that in a file named `.Rprofile`. If you use Rstudio projects a lot, you can save it to the project working directory and it will load every time you boot up Rstudio. Otherwise you can put that line of code in the `Rprofile.site` file in your R directory (mine's located in `\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\etc`) and R should load it by default, though I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Also, there is no such console limit if you use ESS evaluation window in Emacs: http://ess.r-project.org/

Comment: There's no limit in the R.app console on Macs. Thanks Simon Urbanek.